# Does steady flow $\implies$ $\int_{V} \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} dV=0$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow, continuum-mechanics

I'm studying the derivation of the continuity equation for fluids. For steady flow (supposing sections perprendicular to velocity vectors, and assuming velocity is unifrom throughout the sections):

$$\rho_1 S_1 v_1=\rho_2 S_2 v_2\tag{1}$$
Where $\rho$ is density  (which **can also not be constant**), $S$ are the sections and $v$ are velocities.

The only assumptions for the equation (besides the one listed above) above is that the flow is **steady**.

---

The previous equation is derived from the more general **mass conservation principle** which states, for a volume $V$ and the corresponding surface $S$
$$\int_{S} \rho \vec{v} \cdot \hat{n} dS=-\int_{V} \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} dV\tag{2}$$

I understood the principle, which is completely general and do not require any condition for the fluid. Nevertheless it is not clear how is it possible to pass from $(2)$ to $(1)$ in the case of **steady flow**.

I quote the reasoning used for derivation of eq $(1)$ from $(2)$ done on *Cengel-Cimbala*, which is not clear to me:

> During a steady-flow process, the total amount of mass contained within a control volume $V$ does not change with time.

And this means  $$\int_{V} \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} dV=0$$

And from this, using $(2)$ the equation $(1)$ is derived (under condisions of $\vec{v}$ constant and $\vec{v} \, || \, \hat{n}$).

---

The condition of steady flow means $$\frac{\partial \vec{v}(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=0$$

So how is this related to the fact that the "mass in the volume $V$ cannot change"? I do not see how this implication must hold:
$$\frac{\partial \vec{v}(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=0 \implies \int_{V} \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} dV=0$$

Maybe did I interpreted the quote in the wrong way? Or is this implication really true? If so, what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: I'm just guessing as I've got no good references at hand - but could steady flow also imply $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \rho=0$?

Comment: For steady flow, $\partial\, \text{anything} / \partial t = 0$ at any fixed point $(x, y, z)$. You have the "implication" backwards. The $\int_V = 0$ by definition of what "steady" means, therefore the $\int_S = 0$.